# Selecting individual parts of cell <td> using Selenium

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, web-crawler

I have started using selenium to collect data from a website that uses Javascript. I have managed to get to a point where I am able to select the cells from the table but I would now like to be able to select the "Individual" strings from each cell, for example:

This is a cell from the table:

```
<tr data-ig="x:360964033.17:adr:0:tag:" tag="" adr="0" type="row">
   <td idx="0" adr="0" type="cell">2014-11-02 21:15:00</td>
   <td idx="1" adr="1" type="cell">AMALT</td>
   <td idx="2" adr="2" type="cell">60007</td>
   <td idx="3" adr="3" type="cell">107115</td>
   <td class="ig9a63765d">1</td>
   <td idx="9" adr="9" type="cell">576833</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to be able to select the `<td idx="0" adr="0" type="cell">2014-11-02 21:15:00</td>` rows in the cell individually, how is this possible? 
I want to be able to do something like this `List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("idx=0"));` but that doesn't work.

I am collecting the table and cells as a whole like this:

```
 // Now get all the TR elements from the table 
         List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 
         // And iterate over them, getting the cells 
         for (WebElement row : allRows) { 
             List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 

             // Print the contents of each cell
             for (WebElement cell : cells) { 
                 System.out.println(cell.getText());
             }break;
         }
```

Thank you.

Update, the table layout has changed to:

```
<tr data-ig="x:360964033.17:adr:0:tag:" tag="" adr="0" type="row">
      <td>2014-11-04 23:00:00</td>
      <td idx="1" adr="1" type="cell">gasdjjhg</td>
      <td idx="2" adr="2" type="cell">11344</td>
      <td idx="3" adr="3" type="cell">14500</td>
      <td idx="4" adr="4" type="cell">saddasd</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>sdsed</td>
      <td>dsfdsf</td>
      <td class="ig9a63765d">1</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
```

The table Layout keeps changing?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `idx` is not a tag, it's an attribute. In Selenium you can select based on attribute, using XPath:

```
table.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@idx=0]"))
```

Comment: Thanks but this is giving a "no such element" exception, the data is there definitely.

Comment: Hang on...no I was wrong, when I first tried your solution it worked but the next 5 times it didn't, I had other things going on in the code and put the first result down to something else but I believe your code is correct, what HAS changed is the table in the last hour! instead of my original table layout in the question it has changed to (see updated question). Strange how that has changed in the last hour?

Comment: Then you have to post more code. In your sample above, `table` is not defined.

Comment: I'm thinking now if it would be better to select the rows in the cells by the <td  rather than something that could be changing, is it possible to collect it something like: '(By.xpath("//td[0]"))' as the <td is going to remain constant??

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**Note:** Assuming the **'data-ig'** value doesn't change.

```
    List allRows = table.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@data-ig='x:360964033.17:adr:0:tag:']/td"));
    for(WebElement row: allRows){
    System.out.println(row.getText());
    }
```